# Does JDK include Java-EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

As I know `JDK` is used to develop `Java-SE` application. Now, I need to develop a `Java-EE` application so does JDK include libraries for `Java-EE`?

Comment: You need to read  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860513/java-ee-and-jdk   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024143/jdk-java-se-jdk-java-ee and this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438127/is-there-a-java-ee-jdk

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not.
Java EE is a specification - and its implementation can be downloaded in form of an application server (e.g. GlassFish).

You may want to start by downloading [Netbeans EE edition + GlassFish bundle](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and consult the [Java EE 7 turorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm).

Comment: Hi, with Java EE(J2EE) 1.4 I can download Java EE 1.4 SDK(not GlassFish), install and use Java EE. But I cannot find a Java EE SDK for Java EE 7. Please, help me to understand.

Comment: Back then the Sun Java System Application Server was the reference implementation for J2EE. With Java EE 5 the project GlassFish was started and is until now the reference implementation for Java EE. But in both cases, you download an application server, which implements all of the mandatory specifications for a specific Java Enterprise version.

Answer (score 1):

No. These are part of the application server you will work with - whichever that will be.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

Java EE is an API, means that it does not have implementation, but only provides interfaces.
Java EE consist of many parts, like EJB, Servlets, JTA, JPA, CDI etc. If you want to use some of these features, you have to choose corresponding implementation (usually this is web or application server, frameworks etc).